# No parentheses function "call" in Lua example from official docs

Tags: lua

The official [documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.1.html) for metatables in Lua shows the following code:

```
Set = {}
    
    function Set.new (t)
      local set = {}
      for _, l in ipairs(t) do set[l] = true end
      return set
    end
    
    function Set.union (a,b)
      local res = Set.new{}
      for k in pairs(a) do res[k] = true end
      for k in pairs(b) do res[k] = true end
      return res
    end
```

The syntax `Set.new{}` is unclear to me. `new` is a function and typically functions are called with parentheses `()`. What is this syntax and where is it documented in [lua.org](https://www.lua.org)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua allows the syntax of passing a string literal or table constructor into a function as its only param without needing to wrap it with parentheses, which in my opinion is hideous.

You will find it covered in [Programming in Lua: 5 – Functions](https://www.lua.org/pil/5.html).

> If the function has one single argument and this argument is either a literal string or a table constructor, then the parentheses are optional:
>
> ```
>    print "Hello World"     <-->     print("Hello World")
>    dofile 'a.lua'          <-->     dofile ('a.lua')
>    print [[a multi-line    <-->     print([[a multi-line
>     message]]                        message]])
>    f{x=10, y=20}           <-->     f({x=10, y=20})
>    type{}                  <-->     type({})
> ```

You can also find it in the refrence manaul [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: 3.4.10 – Function Calls](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.10)

> A call of the form f{fields} is syntactic sugar for f({fields}); that is, the argument list is a single new table. A call of the form f'string' (or f"string" or f[[string]]) is syntactic sugar for f('string'); that is, the argument list is a single literal string.

Comment: Yes, very hideous and rather arbitrary in my opinion. But I'll go with it ...

Comment: Note that a space isn't required for either tables or strings.

Comment: @user32882: Not hideous at all and very, very useful when building DSLs using Lua; otherwise some DSLs would be horribly inconcise.

Comment: I like this "hideous" syntax. Also [same topic in reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.10).

Comment: @Green Thank you, I will add the topic from the reference manual to the answer.